# Generic template template parameters

Tags: c++, templates, c++17, template-templates

Fed up with "uniform initialisation" not being very uniform, I decided to write a generic `construct()` wrapper which uses aggregate initialisation if a type is an aggregate, and direct initialisation otherwise:

```
template <class T, class... Args,
          std::enable_if_t<std::is_aggregate_v<T>, int> = 0>
constexpr auto construct(Args&&... args)
    -> decltype(T{std::forward<Args>(args)...})
{
    return T{std::forward<Args>(args)...};
}

template <class T, class... Args>
constexpr auto construct(Args&&... args)
   -> decltype(T(std::forward<Args>(args)...))
{
    return T(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
}
```

This works well enough:

```
template <class T, class U>
struct my_pair { T first; U second; };

auto p = construct<my_pair<int, float>>(1, 3.14f);
auto v = construct<std::vector<int>>(5, 0);
```

I'd like to extend this to use template argument deduction for constructors. So I added another pair of overloads:

```
template <template <class...> class T, // <-- (1) 
          class... Args,
          class A = decltype(T{std::declval<Args>()...}),
          std::enable_if_t<std::is_aggregate_v<A>, int> = 0>
constexpr auto construct(Args&&... args)
    -> decltype(T{std::forward<Args>(args)...})
{
     return T{std::forward<Args>(args)...};
}

template <template <class...> class T, // <-- (1)
          class... Args>
constexpr auto construct(Args&&... args)
    -> decltype(T(std::forward<Args>(args)...))
{
    return T(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
}
```

Perhaps surprisingly (at least to me), this works for simple cases:

```
// deduction guide for my_pair
template <class T, class U> my_pair(T&&, U&&) -> my_pair<T, U>;

auto p = construct<my_pair>(1, 3.14f); // my_pair<int, float>
auto v = construct<std::vector>(5, 0); // vector of 5 ints
```

Unfortunately however this fails when trying to call

```
auto a = construct<std::array>(1, 2, 3); // No matching call to construct()
```

because `std::array` has a non-type template parameter, so it doesn't match the `template <class...> class T` template template parameter at (1).

So my question is, is there a way to formulate the parameter at (1) such that it can accept *any* class template name, regardless of the kind (type or non-type) of its template parameters?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unfortunately, there is no proper way of doing this without code repetition. The newly added "`auto` as template parameter" in C++17 only supports *non-type template parameters*.

The only way I can think this could work is by using a code generator to generate a fixed amount of permutations of `auto` and `class`. E.g.

```
template <
    template <class, auto...> class T,
    class... Args>
constexpr auto construct(Args&&... args) // ...

template <
    template <class, auto, class...> class T,
    class... Args>
constexpr auto construct(Args&&... args) // ...

template <
    template <auto, class, auto...> class T,
    class... Args>
constexpr auto construct(Args&&... args) // ...

template <
    template <auto, class, auto, class...> class T,
    class... Args>
constexpr auto construct(Args&&... args) // ...

template <
    template <auto, class, auto, class, auto...> class T,
    class... Args>
constexpr auto construct(Args&&... args) // ...

// and so on...
```

[**live example on wandbox**](https://wandbox.org/permlink/rR9dr0zIjnvEbO11)

*Sounds like you have a good idea for a proposal...*

Comment: `template <class, auto...>` seems sufficient? :) Probably covers all the real cases (`std::array`, `std::integer_sequence`) anyway.

Comment: @Barry: it probably is good enough in 99% of the cases, but if I were distributing a library containing `construct` I would probably generate a few more cases just to make sure it can handle 99.9999% :)

Comment: *sigh* thanks, that was the answer I was expecting but I thought there might be a fancy workaround. "Sounds like you have a good idea for a proposal" -- I was thinking about this [a while ago](https://groups.google.com/a/isocpp.org/forum/?utm_medium=email&utm_source=footer#!msg/std-proposals/LssgltuyOF4/Hp0K2KJgAQAJ), pre-C++17. `std::is_aggregate` and constructor type deduction change things a bit though.